# Is there a standard way to write a second definite integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, notation, physics

This question arose in the context of writing the equations of kinematics for a point mass with constant acceleration.  The integration parameter $t$ represents time.

This is so basic that I didn't even realize I didn't know how to do it.  I define $\Delta t$ as the definite integral of $1$ from $t_0$ to $t$ as shown.  I then integrate $\Delta t$  from $t_0$ to $t$ producing the desired result.

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt=\Delta t&=t-t_{0}\\
\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\Delta tdt&=\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\left(t-t_{0}\right)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}t^{2}-tt_{0}-\left(\frac{1}{2}t_{0}^{2}-t_{0}^{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(t-t_{0}\right)^{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Delta t^{2}
\end{aligned}$$

I might write that as
$$\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt\right)dt=\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\Delta t^{2}.$$

In that case, the upper bound of integration of the inner integral is the value of the integration variable of the outer integral, so $t$ has two meanings.

To show why I find this problematic, I will make the upper bound of integration more explicit.  Suppose I treat the upper bound of integration as a specific fixed value $t_{1}$.  Then the inner integral behaves as a constant with respect to the second integral, and I get a different result.

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt=\Delta t&=t_{1}-t_{0}\\
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt^{2}&=\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\Delta tdt\\
&=\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\left(t_{1}-t_{0}\right)dt\\
&=\Delta t\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt\\
&=\Delta t^{2}
\end{aligned}$$

One remedy I might propose is to write the bound of the outer integral as $t_{1}$ and leave the bound of the inner integral as the dependent variable $t$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}dt=\Delta t&=t_{1}-t_{0}\\
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt^{2}
&=\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\left(t-t_{0}\right)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Delta t^{2}
\end{aligned}$$

It appears to communicate my intent, but I don't recall having encountered that use of notation in the case of a second integral (as opposed to the more general case of a double integral).  Where I have encountered such integrals in textbooks, the authors typically speak of antiderivatives and constants of integration, etc., or sidestep the entire problem by writing two separate subsequent integrals.

Is there a standard way of writing what I am here calling second definite integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the two variables of integration different:
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \int_{t_0}^u dt\,du  $$

This is a consequence of the general idea that to minimize confusion the variable of integration *should not* be chosen as a letter that is already bound to a value outside of the integral. You're breaking this principle already at the beginning when you write
$$ \int_{t_0}^t dt$$

(Yes, this is in contrast to the Leibniz notation for *derivatives*, where the same variable letter is used inside and outside the $\frac{d}{dx}$ operator. But the notation we have is the notation we have, and trying to straighten it out is usually not worth the risk of confusion).

Comment: Since my topic is kinematics, $t$ means time.  This is one example of how physicists think about mathematics differently from mathematicians.  Physicists pretend to know what they are talking about, so they give functions and variables names based on what is being represented.  Since (pure) mathematicians don't pretend to know what they are talking about (per Russell) they name variables and functions "arbitrarily".

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Sometimes people use $d\tau$ and $dt$ if there are two time-like variables.

Comment: I intend no disrespect by not accepting this answer.  @Miscellaneous  The suggestion of using $d\tau$ is consistent with what I have done elsewhere.  I will note that C.H. Edwards https://store.doverpublications.com/0486683362.html treats the $dt$ typically found in an integral as an embarrassing artifact of historical delusion.  And proceeds to use it in more advanced settings.  But, using his notation , my $\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt^{2}$ becomes $\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{t_{0}}^{t}1$.  The $1$ is actually superfluous.

Comment: I haven't come up with a better way to do this. So I am accepting the answer.